# RVM and Rails (3.2) Path Problems OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have rails and RVM installed on OSx 10.7.4

If I do this

```
$ cd ~/
$ rails -v
```

I get

```
$ Rails 3.2.3
```

Now if I go into a rails application with

```
$ cd ~/rails-project/
Using ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320 with gemset ourgemset
```

The .vmrc file in the rails app looks like this

```
rvm use --create 1.9.2@ourgemset
```

However when I try and use rails now I get

```
$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

My ~/.bash_profile has this line at the end of it (and these scripts exist)

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

I've no idea why this is happening or where to look to solve it.

**EDIT:**

On further investigation if I do the following

```
$ rvm use default
Using ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194 with gemset anothergemset
```

Now rails works fine. If I switch back to

```
$rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p320
```

I can't use rails anymore. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your global env has Rails but your gemset does not contain the rails gem. So when you are in `cd ~/rails-project/` run the command:

```
gem install rails
```

it will install the gem to your rvm gemset.